# How to keep control-specific css with the control code (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, custom-controls

If I'm writing an ASCX control, and that control has markup that requires CSS, and that CSS will only be used by the control itself, is there an elegant way (besides just sticking it in the ASCX file itself) to include the .css file with it?

Ideally, I'd have control.ascx, control.ascx.cs, control.js, and control.css all as a little "package".

It brings up one problem and one concern so far:

Problem: Since the control is in a subdirectory, I don't want to use a  tag hardcoded with the knoweldge that the css is in a subfolder.  I'd like to write it so that it's relative to the control code (ie: same folder) but still be found at runtime.

Concern: If I did this for ten controls, it's ten more server hits I suppose.  Maybe ScriptManager or the RadScriptManager or RadStyleSheet manager will magically aggregate them, but its not a showstopper for me either way.

Any ideas on how to solve the relative-path issue?

Comment: You can use the App_Themes folder and have your control specific CSS in different .css files here. They will all be automatically referenced/linked to at run time and the classes/styles will be available for use in your html. I prefer this to keeping my styles with the controls as it keeps all of the CSS in one place - convenient for playing "hunt the broken style" (which is made less fun by "where the heck is the css" for this class) for example ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct path of your stylesheet relative to the *page*, call the `ResolveClientUrl` method of your user control, passing it the path of the stylesheet relative to the *control*:

```
HtmlLink link = new HtmlLink();
link.Href = this.ResolveClientUrl("control.css"); // same directory as the control
link.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
link.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
```

Although each stylesheet will result in a separate request, you can mitigate the issue by enabling content expiration for them.